# send sensor values from Beaglebone Black to a socket server on Windows

Tags: python, sockets, beagleboneblack

I have a python TCP socket client code on my Beaglebone Black which reads data from the sensor and sends it to a server. My server is on Windows in Visual Studio and it's written in C#. The Beaglebone Black and Windows PC connected via SSH using Putty. The problem is that the server and the client don't see each other. However, everything works when I use Ubuntu PC (server written on python) instead of Windows.

Could you please help me to establish the connection. I think the problem is on the server side.

P.S. The server must be written in C# due to future plans.

Here is my C# server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Server_Tutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.7.1").AddressList[0];
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ip, 7000);
            TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);

            try
            {
                server.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Server started...");
                Console.Read();
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.Read();
            }

            while (true)
            {
                client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[100];
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();


                stream.Read(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);

                StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (byte b in receivedBuffer)
                {
                    if (b.Equals(00))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        msg.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString() + msg.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is client code in python:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC
import time
import socket
import sys

serverAddr = ('192.168.7.1', 7000)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(serverAddr)

fsr = 'P9_40'

ADC.setup()

while True:
        reading = ADC.read(fsr)*1000
        reading = int(round(reading))
        client.send(str(reading))

client.close()
```

And this is server code in python that works on Ubuntu:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''
PORT = 7000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
        print('Bind failed. ')
        sys.exit()

print('Socket bind complete')

s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected to ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        line = data.decode('UTF-8')    # convert to string (Python 3 only)
        line = line.replace("\n","")   # remove newline character
        print( line )

s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run:
`netstat -a -b`

on your PC?

If it were to show that your port 7000 is already been used by another TCP connection you could simply switch to `port 8080`  or another of your liking to successfully connect.